# When is usefull use ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

i'm new to ServiceStack, so forgive me.
i'd like to know when is usefull use ServiceStack.
For example, if i've to create a console app that not exposes services, creating an appHost is not right, do you confirm?
If i understand, servicestack (and so create an apphost) is usefull if i've to create a self-hosted console app or a web app or however something that expose a service (which could be a simple authentication service)
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AppHost is required for all ServiceStack Apps where you're using ServiceStack to host your APIs.

ServiceStack has a number of starting project templates at: https://servicestack.net/start

In .NET5/6 all Web Apps are Console Apps:

Some non traditional HTTP Web Apps you can use ServiceStack for include [gRPC Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc), [Worker Services](https://servicestack.net/start#workers) which hosts APIs in background workers
and potentially [AWS Lambda](https://servicestack.net/start#empty) as it's for running your ServiceStack App in AWS Lambda.

You wouldn't use an AppHost if you're not using ServiceStack to host your APIs, e.g. if you're just using a component in one of ServiceStack's stand-alone libraries:

- [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) - Typed Client for Redis
- [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) - Lightweight POCO ORM for RDBMS access
- [ServiceStack.Aws](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws) - Poco Dynamo and SQS, S3, DynamoDB support
- [ServiceStack.Azure](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Azure) - Connectors for Service Bus, Azure Blob, Table Storage, etc
- [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) - JSON/CSV/JSV Serializers, Auto Mapping, HTTP Utils, etc.

Comment: Thanks! It’s all more clear!